# Magento v. 2.1.4 Readiness Check Fails at Component Dependancy

Tags: composer, dependency, component-manager

No other information is given.
  (Or, if it is, I do not know where to look for it.)

I have a clean Magento install, no theme, no extensions, nothing.

I am on a shared server so direct `php.ini` edits are not available.
   (But, yes, I have adjusted memory limits through Cpanel as per articles found here and on github.)

I do have CLI access.

Running:
**Magento 2.1.4**, **PHP 5.6**, **MySQL 5.6**, **Server OS Linux**.

Any helpful ideas would be welcome. I am well and truly stuck. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe add your own file to the site with the contents `<?php echo phpinfo();` and compare your loaded modules with Magento's system requirements?

Comment: Try deleting/renaming:
<your Magento install dir>/var/.update_cronjob_status and <your Magento install dir>/var/.setup_cronjob_status.

Also, check your file permissions are correct, it will often have a hissy-fit if it finds something that isn't spot on.

Comment: Also as Meogi suggested, use the phpinfo trick to check that the memory limits that you increased have taken effect.

Comment: Thank you! A place to begin. I'm new so not sure what protocols are, but I will certainly update as soon as I have tried your suggestions. I appreciate it!

Comment: Thanx, Guys. I'm not too sure how to setup this <?php echo phpinfo(); that's a new one for me.

I did try renaming var/.update_cronjob_status and .setup, but the site loaded a blank page after that.